# Make binary operation on columns with the same name in the dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

I have dataset which has columns with the same names.

```
    name check_id a b a b
1 item_1    00192 1 0 0 0
2 item_2    21231 0 1 0 0
3 item_3     2413 1 0 0 1
4 item_1    23423 1 0 0 0
5 item_4      232 0 0 1 0
6 item_3      232 1 0 0 1
```

I need to leave only one `a` and one `b` column by applying `or` operation between the columns with the same name.

Comment: You can use column numbers when names are not unique, or you can refactor the names to be unique. The refactoring will be done automatically if you do `your_data = data.frame(your_data)`. (You will end up with `a` and `a.1`, `b` and `b.1`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example using the names. It's a bit tricky and possibly fragile, but it works on your sample data, and should scale up even if you have more than 2 duplicates.

```
d = read.table(text = '    name check_id a b a b
1 item_1    00192 1 0 0 0
2 item_2    21231 0 1 0 0
3 item_3     2413 1 0 0 1
4 item_1    23423 1 0 0 0
5 item_4      232 0 0 1 0
6 item_3      232 1 0 0 1', header = T, check.names = F)

names_to_replace = c("a", "b")
new_cols = list()

for (n in names_to_replace) {
  # calculate new column
  new_cols[[n]] = as.integer(Reduce(f = "|", x = d[names(d) == n]))
  # drop old columns
  d[names(d) == n] = list(NULL)
}
d = cbind(d, new_cols)
#     name check_id a b
# 1 item_1      192 1 0
# 2 item_2    21231 0 1
# 3 item_3     2413 1 1
# 4 item_1    23423 1 0
# 5 item_4      232 1 0
# 6 item_3      232 1 1
```